# .Net Core published application need chmod 777 permissions to run on Centos7

Tags: bash, .net-core, cross-platform, centos7, self-contained

```
chmod 777 ./myapp
```

Why do i need to provide chmod 777 to myapp after every publish.
Without providing permissions the result of `./myapp` is:   Permission denied. Even when logged in using `root` user.

Are there any alternatives to do this?

Comment: Whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve, **giving other users write access to your program is a *serious* security flaw** and an antipattern. You need to understand the permission model and grant the permissions which the problem requires but absolutely no more (typically 755 for a script or 711 for a directory which users need to access but not read).

Comment: What version of .NET Core are you using? Sounds like you are hitting https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/1338

Comment: I am using .NET Core 2.0 and issue looks same.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is "publishing" the app needs to write it with the correct permissions. You are not showing us how you are doing that so we can't tell you what exactly is wrong, but something like

```
chmod 755 myapp   # only really required the first time
scp myapp prod:/srv/myapp/
```

If you are using a version control system like Git, the permissions change is a change you need to commit in order to preserve it.

```
chmod 755 myapp
git add myapp
git commit -m "fixed permissions" myapp
```

Now every check-out should have the correct permissions and you can forget about this until next time you start a new project.

Comment: Possibly I am revealing my complete ignorance about .Net -- maybe "publish" has a specific and very precise meaning there. But the basic idea probably still holds.